# Laravel 4 IoC + ServiceProvider + name space = Log class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I developed a service that do auto translate.

When I try to use:

```
App::Make('AnotherPakage')
```

or

```
Log::info('test')
```

I get class not found: vendor/pacakgename/Log

where vendor/pacakgename is the name space.

What is the correct to work with the IoC in a ServiceProvider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a namespaced file:

```
<?php namespace vendor/packagename;

class MyClass {

}
```

To use

```
Log::info()
```

You have two options:

```
\Log::info()
```

**OR**, add a `use` clause before your code:

```
use Log;
```

Otherwise PHP will think that the class is inside your namespace and will give you this error:

```
'class not found: vendor/packagename/Log'
```